# Can't get rupee symbol to show correctly from strings.xml

Tags: android, string, kotlin, symbols

So this works fine:

```
strFoo = "\u20B9" + strBar
```

But this doesn't

```
strFoo = R.string.rupee_symbol.toString() + strBar  //.toString() is required

//R.string.rupee_symbol.toString() evaluates to some random number 2131755148... which I believe is a character array...
```

strings.xml

```
<string name="rupee_symbol">\u20B9 </string>
```

I can't figure out why it would behave like that, it looks like the same thing...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not concatenate strings with string resources instead, you can use place holder:

```
<string name="rupee_symbol">\u20B9%s</string>
```

And use:

```
strFoo = resources.getString(R.string.rupee_symbol, strBar)
```

Comment: Means? How do I use a placeholder?

Comment: @whoadityanawandar.. Using the symbol `%s`, means that you will fill this placeholder later in the code; and this is filled with `strBar` using the two-argument version of `getString()`

Comment: @whoadityanawandar, I mistenkly used `$` instead of `%`, I fixed it now

Answer (score 1):

use `getString(R.string.rupee_symbol)` instead `R.string.rupee_symbol.toString()`

```
For example- 
String strBar = String.valueOf(100);
    String strFoo = getString(R.string.rupee_symbol)+strBar;
    textView.setText( strFoo);
```